# Which Queue will be used while running this job is sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, sidekiq-cron

Hi I am using sidekiq_cron in my rails project. Jobs classes are from ActiveJob. In my job file I have **queue_as :default** and in schedule.yml file I have **queue: high_priority**. In actual which queue will be used?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [sidekiq-cron](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron)? It seems that it allows you to pick the queue so one should expect `high_priority` queue to be used when jobs are scheduled by cron, and `default` queue to be used when the same jobs are scheduled by other means (other Ruby code that is not the cron).

You have a way to confirm this, spin up locally a sidekiq that does not process jobs in any of these queues, set your cron to every minute, and in your Sidekiq web dashboard you will be able to see jobs accumulating on the Queues tab.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you, did the same and I was able to figure it out.